# (MVC) do you recommend me to pass model and view to controller using setter?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

When initializing controllers using the MVC pattern, I have seen this a lot:

```
main {
    // initialize view
    View view = new view()
    // initialize model
    Model model = new Model();
    // initialize controller
    Controller controller = new Controller(model, view);
}
```

But I haven't seen this:

```
 main {
    // initialize view
    View view = new view()
    // initialize model
    Model model = new Model();
    // initialize controller with empty constructor
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    // pass model and view using setter
    controller.setView(view);
    controller.setModel(model);
}
```

The reason why I'm asking is that I want to use the same controller to manage different objects, and I don't feel that is appropriately creating a new controller every time I want to pass a new object to the same controller.

my entire Main class looks like this (I'm using setters to pass the model and the view to the respective controllers):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // store message in final string
        final String GET_NUM_EMPLOYEES = "Enter the number of Employees:\n";
        // store message in final string
        final String GET_EMPLOYEE_DATA = "Enter data for employee #%d:\n";
        // store message in final string
        final String GET_EMPLOYEE_TYPE = "Select type for employee #%d: \n(1) Hourly \n(2) Salaried\n";
        // store message in final string
        final String INVALID_INPUT = "Invalid input, please try again.";

        // Initialize view
        final View VIEW = new View();

        // initialize controllers
        NameController nameController = new NameController();
        AddressController addressController = new AddressController();
        DateController dateController = new DateController();
        SalariedEmployeeController salariedEmployeeController = new SalariedEmployeeController();
        HourlyEmployeeController hourlyEmployeeController = new HourlyEmployeeController();

        // pass view to controllers (same view will be used for all controllers)
        nameController.setView(VIEW);
        addressController.setView(VIEW);
        dateController.setView(VIEW);
        salariedEmployeeController.setView(VIEW);
        hourlyEmployeeController.setView(VIEW);

        // prompt the user for number of employees and validate the input
        final int EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = Validation.getPositiveInteger(
                VIEW,
                GET_NUM_EMPLOYEES,
                INVALID_INPUT);

        // create Employee array with size equal to employeeNumber
        final Employee[] EMPLOYEES = new Employee[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER];

        // fill the Employees array with data using a for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEES.length; i++) {

            // pass models to controllers
            nameController.setModel(new Name());
            addressController.setModel(new Address());
            dateController.setModel(new Date());
            salariedEmployeeController.setModel(new SalariedEmployee());
            hourlyEmployeeController.setModel(new HourlyEmployee());

            // prompt the user for employee type and validate the input
            final int EMPLOYEE_TYPE = Validation.getNumberOneOrTwo(
                    VIEW,
                    String.format(GET_EMPLOYEE_TYPE, i + 1),
                    INVALID_INPUT);

            // prompt the user for Employee data
            VIEW.updateUserInterface(String.format(GET_EMPLOYEE_DATA, i + 1));

            // populate models
            nameController.setFirstName();
            nameController.setLastName();
            addressController.setStreet();
            addressController.setCity();
            addressController.setState();
            addressController.setZipCode();
            dateController.setDay();
            dateController.setMonth();
            dateController.setYear();

            // populate employee based on the type
            switch (EMPLOYEE_TYPE) {
                case 1: {
                    hourlyEmployeeController.setName(nameController.getObject());
                    hourlyEmployeeController.setAddress(addressController.getObject());
                    hourlyEmployeeController.setDate(dateController.getObject());
                    hourlyEmployeeController.setHourlyRate();
                    hourlyEmployeeController.setHoursWorked();
                    // Add hourly employee to employees array
                    EMPLOYEES[i] = hourlyEmployeeController.getObject();
                }
                case 2: {
                    salariedEmployeeController.setName(nameController.getObject());
                    salariedEmployeeController.setAddress(addressController.getObject());
                    salariedEmployeeController.setDate(dateController.getObject());
                    salariedEmployeeController.setSalary();
                    // Add salary employee to employees array
                    EMPLOYEES[i] = salariedEmployeeController.getObject();
                }
            }
        }

        // use a for each loop to display all Employees
        for (Employee e : EMPLOYEES) {
            VIEW.updateUserInterface(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with passing the view and model separately, is it raises a risk that one or the other won't be called.  What would be the point of a controller without either of these things?  It would seem kind of pointless to me.  As to your "reason", why would your controller be using multiple models?  Wouldn't it need a model which contained a list of employees?

Comment: Hello @MadProgrammer, thanks for the response. I have included the code for my main class. I hope it helps to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer), the use of setter to pass the view and model to your controler causes the risk of an incomplete initialization.

In cases like yours where you want to manage several object as models, it is more likely that a model containing a collection of your objects should be used.

In the example you gave, the models (Name, Address, Date...) are re-created at each iteration. Rather than that, you could reset them to default values at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hello @ebigeon, thanks for your response. The reason why I'm creating a new object at each iteration (Name, Address, Date, ...) is that I'm passing that object to a model of type Employee and maintaining each new Employee on an array to use those employees latter.  If I use a collection of objects, as you said, and then I reset the objects at each iteration, won't I lose the employee data content? As far as I know, java passes a reference of the object (Name, Address, Date) to the model employee, not a copy.

Comment: Indeed, I just assumed that you extracted the actual data (name, address, date...) from the models and stored the information as separate in the Employee objects. If you store the models directly, then I would suggest to create an array of employees with the "models" already set. Then selecting an employee in your view would simply update the index of the emplyee in your collection and access the inner models by accessors on the employee model.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the picture for [mvc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you will *not* see a dependency from the controller to the view. You can use the same instance of a controller for many models (assuming that they are the same) if you allow your controller to cycle through the models.